# Interfacing Hadoop nodes with third-party software

Tags: hadoop

### What I understand from Hadoop

Whenever I submit code to my Hadoop cluster :

1. The hadoop `map` function is executed and attributes calculations to the data nodes
2. My `map` function is executed on each node on the local data
3. My `reduce` function is executed on each node
4. Once a node has finished its task, it sends back result to the master node
5. The hadoop `reduce` function is executed and aggregates results.

### The question itself

Assuming the steps described before are corrects, what would be the requirements in order to change step 2 from this :

```
public void map(Args args) {
    for(Arg arg : args)
        someCalculations(arg);    
}
```

into this :

```
public void map(Args args) {
    executeOtherSofwareAndFetchResultst(args);
}
```

For instance, would the other software need HDFS compatibility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapper acts just like a normal Java instance. You can do whatever you can do with normal Java programs in the mapper.
Consider it as another Java instance and as long as you are getting the data into the mapper, you dont need any software compatibility with HDFS, because the mapper deals with it and not the logic inside it.

Comment: If I follow you well, I won't have problems reading data block with other software as long as I read them from java ?

Comment: The mapper reads the data and passes it to your map function in the mapper. Why do you want to externally read data, when the mapper itself reads it?

Comment: Should I wish to send the whole data block to some software, I would have to write the data in the mapper in a new file. Reading the block externally would prevent this.

Comment: So instead of reading it from your software, just read the data from HDFS as a normal java code and use it in your software logic. This might help you:
Path pt=new Path("hdfs://npvm11.np.wc1.yellowpages.com:9000/user/john/abc.txt");
                        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
                  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
                        String line;
                        line=br.readLine();
                        while (line != null){
                         line=br.readLine()